# Debian stretch and vagrant: automatically "up" VirtualBox network interface

Tags: virtualbox, debian, vagrant, network-interface

I'm referring to my question @stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45238551/debian-9-stretch-vagrant-vm-box-host-not-reachable

I haven't found out yet why the virtualbox interface hasn't been started immediately after starting the box.

I'm looking for a solution to automatically bring up all VirtualBox interfaces identified by a name beginning with `vboxnet` as soon as they has been created by the VM.

Currently I'm using `ifconfig vboxnet0 up` manually every time I'm bringing up my vagrant box.

---

## Update

In the question linked above I got the hint this is a known issue in VirtualBox 5.1.24. Installing VB 5.1.22 is a accepted solution while it's at least working as expected.

But I still like to know how to automatically bring up any newly appearing netwoirk interfaces.

Comment: Judging by your `ifconfig` you have the `net-tools` package installed; was it installed at the time you deployed the vagrant instance?  I notice that missing `net-tools` causes a similar failure on stretch hosts https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8686

Comment: I found this link as well. `net-tools` was already installed but `/sbin` was not part of `$PATH`. After some trouble while not knowing this I reinstalled `net-tools` by mistake and afterwards I had to reinstall my OS while I'm barely too new to Linux to fix the resulting misconfiguration. After the reinstall of Debian I first made `export PATH=$PATH:/sbin` for my session on system start and afterwards I started my vagrant box. Conclusion: `ifconfig` was accessible to vagrant but didn't change anything.

Comment: May omitting `/sbin` in the environment path isn't enough to omit `net-tools` to vagrant.